# How to resolve a video URL from a f4m manifest file?

Tags: video, download, video-streaming, flv

I want to know the video URL that corresponds to the bitrate 364 in this f4m file:
http://nicls1-lh.akamaihd.net/z/lst_1@26969/manifest.f4m?hdcore=

How can I do that? Is there some software utility which can do that?

Answer (score -1):

Just Check this link :
http://nicls1-lh.akamaihd.net/i/lst_1@26969/master.m3u8

You can use it in any video streaming player ...